# How do I programmatically add a custom layout to a StackView or TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I need to be able to create a custom layout with different components (Labels, Buttons, Images, etc.) and add this layout programmatically to a parent `UIStackView` and be able to reuse this layout and continuously append to the `UIStackView` except changing the properties of the inner views of the custom layout.

Here are a few examples I've found to get an idea of what I'd like to achieve

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am switching from Java (Android Studio) over to Xcode, and I would expect the concept to be similar. The java equivalent would be to create a custom xml layout file and convert it to an object using the LayoutInflater, and adding the inflated object to a LinearLayout while being able to access the sub views using findViewById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on place of stack use the tableview , because in tableview you can reuse the table view cell.

some tutorials of how to use tableview are give in below link with help of them i hope you will achieve your goal.

https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwE3_hMyDZA